# Button не работает при помещении в другой блок

Tags: html, css, button

Окно запуска игры содержит кнопку START. Когда окно в body кнопка работает, а когда я окно помещаю в контейнер - кнопка становится некликабельной.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="canvas">
                <canvas width="800" height="600" id="screen"></canvas>
                <div class="startWindow">
                    <form>
                    <button class="start">Start</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="highscores"></div>

</div>
```

```css
body{
 background-image: url(img/body.jpg);
 z-index: -5;
 
}
.container{
 height: 600px;
 width: 1150px;
 background-color: cyan;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: -1;
}
canvas{
 border:1px solid silver;
 background-color:black ;
 position: relative;
 display: none;
 z-index: 1;
 float: left;
}
.highscores{
 width: 300px;
 height: 600px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 float: right;
 background-color: red;
 border:1px solid silver;

}
.startWindow{
 border: 5px solid green;
 background-image: url(img/startWindow.jpg);
 width: 626px;
 height: 491px;
 z-index: 3;
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto auto;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px green;
 display: none;
}

.start{
 width: 200px;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: auto;
 bottom: 28px;
 background-color: #32CD32;
 border-color: green;
 z-index: 5;
 font-size: 30px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px green;
}
.start:hover{
 box-shadow: 0 0 30px green;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что кнопка у Вас описывается в форме `StartWindow`. Которому в свою очередь присвоен стиль в CSS

```
display: none;
```

А, согласно описанию `display` с параметром `none`

> Временно удаляет элемент из документа. Занимаемое им место не
>   резервируется и веб-страница формируется так, словно элемента и не
>   было.

Если убрать и CSS из `.startWindow` `display: none;`, то блок отображается.